# Axum router rejecting CORS OPTIONS preflight with 405 even with CorsLayer

Tags: rust, cors, http-status-code-405, rust-tower, rust-axum

Before a `fetch` is sent, the browser will send a request method `OPTIONS` to confirm that the API will accept the request from a script with a particular origin.

Chrome shows that the my Axum server is rejecting my client's request with 405. My router looks something like this:

```rust
let app = Router::new()
    .layer(TraceLayer::new_for_http())
    .layer(CorsLayer::permissive())
    .route("/api", post(server));
```

[Router::layer](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/struct.Router.html#method.layer) says *All requests to the router will be processed by the layer’s corresponding middleware.* but I'm not sure its doing its job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.layer()` function is a builder so returns a new `Router`, with the inner routers wrapped. The route `/api` will be tested first and be rejected 405 because only request method `POST` is supported - not `OPTIONS`.

In summary, you need your `CorsLayer` "outside" your route so it can answer `OPTIONS` requests.

Note the example in the documentation:

```rust
// All requests to `first_handler` and `second_handler` will be sent through
// `ConcurrencyLimit`
let app = Router::new().route("/", get(first_handler))
    .route("/foo", get(second_handler))
    .layer(ConcurrencyLimitLayer::new(64))
    // Request to `GET /bar` will go directly to `third_handler` and
    // wont be sent through `ConcurrencyLimit`
    .route("/bar", get(third_handler));
```

By the way, your `TraceLayer` is not tracing your API calls for the same reason!

Try this, and you'll see the `OPTIONS` request logged, and the `POST` should hit your `server`:

```rust
let app = Router::new()
    .route("/api", post(server))
    .layer(CorsLayer::permissive())
    .layer(TraceLayer::new_for_http());
```

Comment: use tower_http::cors::CorsLayer;
use tower_http::trace::TraceLayer;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that solved the cross origin issue for Chrome

```rust
let app = Router::new()
    .route("/api", post(server))
    .layer(CorsLayer::permissive()) <----- PUT IT HERE
    .layer(TraceLayer::new_for_http());
```